# Bot is not sending any messages even though there isnt any error messages

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Im trying to make a discord bot that will send a message when a Minecraft server is online and when it turns off.

heres the code if you need it. (the only thing in the log is the bot has started so i will not be sending the logs

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const axios = require('axios');

let isServerOnline = false;

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Bot is ready!`);
});

setInterval(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('monkecraftsmp.feathermc.gg');
    if (response.status === 200 && !isServerOnline) {
      isServerOnline = true;
      console.log("Server is online");
      const channel = client.channels.cache.get('917953832431026276');
      channel.send('✅ Server is online');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (isServerOnline) {
      isServerOnline = false;
      console.log("Server has stopped");
      const channel = client.channels.cache.get('917953832431026276');
      channel.send(' Server has stopped');
    }
  }
}, 6000);
```

also if you need it the discord.js version is 12

I have tried to check if the channel id is the right one and it is, then i checked if the token is right and its right.
i have checked the logs and nothing has shown up in it.

Comment: You say nothing has shown up in the logs, does that include "Server is online" not showing up? It might be worth checking into whether the condition in your `if` statement ever actually evaluates to `true`. I'm not familiar with axios, but you might need to include a scheme like `https://` or `http://` for that request. Additionally, if it's a minecraft server, it doesn't necessarily run an HTTP server (loading the url didn't work), so you're not going to get a 200 response there (you won't get any.)

Comment: A minecraft-specific helper like `minecraft-server-status` may help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/minecraft-server-status-simple

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using an API, as this isn't (as far as i know) how Minecraft server statusses work. Check out [this one](https://mcapi.us) as i've seen it's pretty good.

You're also not recieving an error because it's in a try catch statement. You can console.log the error for info on what's going wrong.

Comment: For the api you provided i was unable to download it and just gives errors. And with the api it just keeps saying its offline

Comment: @normaluser You're not meant to download it, you're meant to use a get request to the api for info